# Passing parameter from view to controller for multiple iteration

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My controller is retrieving the follow:

```
def index
    @segments = Segment.all
    @products = Product.all
end
```

But it is not what I want. I want to iterate products based on its `segment_id`. Something like this:

```
def index
    @segments = Segment.all
    @products = Product.where(segment_id: x)
end
```

The problem is: **how to pass `x` from view to controller?**

My view is:

```
- @segments.each do |s|
    - @products.each do |p|
        This is a product from #{s.name}.
```

Ok, **where's the issue?** I'm not showing specific products of specific segments. I'm showing products of all segments. What I need is something like this:

```
- @segments.each do |s|
    - @products(segment_id: s.id).each do |p|
        This is a product from #{s.name}.
```

Can you understand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set up `has_many` association between Segment and Product model.

```
class Segment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end


class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :segment
end
```

Add `segment_id` in the `products` table.

Generate the migration with

`rails g migration add_segment_id_to_products segment_id:integer:index`

Run `rake db:migrate`

Setting up the association would give you dynamic method `products` for an instance of segment which you can use in the view for iteration.

Then update the index action as:

```
def index
    @segments = Segment.all
end
```

Update the view as:

```
- @segments.each do |s|
    - s.products.each do |p|
        This is a product from #{s.name}.
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this do?

```
def index
  @segments = Segment.includes(:products).all
end
```

And in your view:

```
- @segments.each do |s|
  - s.products.each do |p|
    This is product #{p.name} from segment #{s.name}
```

You can add where conditions to the query for both segmens and products if you want to filter them in any way you need like this.

```
Segment.includes(:products).where(:seg_val => 'something', :product => [:prod_val => 'other']).all
```